Stack Overflow AI logo bad contrast
In dark mode, the "Stack Overflow AI" logo in the left sidebar has a bad contrast:


Working as intended, the less we see of AI, the better ;-)

@Cerbrus but the logo shows more of AI! They should invert the colors for it to work as intended ;)

I must have reflexively closed it

This is even worse on high-contrast dark mode, the black text is completely invisible.
